# Why is image downloading instead of just expanding?

Tags: support, images, imgur

The SO question [hide and show jquery - DOES NOT WORK But works fine with fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540868/hide-and-show-jquery-does-not-work-but-works-fine-with-fiddle) contains two images. There's an image of the form in the web page, and clicking on it links to a new page, which shows the image in its own window. This is the normal behavior of clicking on images in questions. The image URL is https://i.stack.imgur.com/COaP4.jpg.

Below that there's an image showing the Developer Tools console. When I click on that, it downloads the image to a file on my computer instead of linking to a new page. Why is that? Its image URL is https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cpoe.jpg.

Comment: I got `Content-Type:application/octet-stream` in the response for the second image but not for the first one.